# Laravel MySQL relation difficulties

Tags: mysql, relational-theory, pivot, development

I have a "users" table:

[image]

And an organisations table ("orgs"):

[image]

And this is the pivot table:

[image]

I have some relations:

On the "users" table, I have a function called "orgs()" which is a belongsToMany relation to "orgs" (org_user,org_id,user_id).

On the "orgs" table, I have a function called "users()" which is a hasMany relation to "users" (org_user,org_id_user_id).

Now, in Laravel, when I do:

```
$orgUser = new OrgUser;
$orgUser->org_id=$org->id;
$orgUser->user_id=$user->id;
$orgUser->role_id=10;
$orgUser->save();
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eamorr`.`org_user`, CONSTRAINT `org_user_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `org_user` (`org_id`, `user_id`, `role_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 1, -1, 2015-07-22 10:29:04, 2015-07-22 10:29:04))'
```

I would have thought I could just do something like:

`$org->users()->attach(...)`

or similar instead of having to reference the "org_user" table directly?

Does anyone have any experience at this?

Here's the User.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract {

    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use Authenticatable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function orgs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Org', 'org_user', 'org_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('role_id');
    }

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\File', 'user_id');
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\User', 'user_user', 'owner_id', 'client_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\UserTag', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

And here's the Org.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Org extends Model {

    protected $table = 'orgs';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\File', 'org_id');
    }

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Location', 'org_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\OrgTag', 'org_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\User', 'org_user', 'org_id_user_id')->withPivot('role_id');
    }

}
```

And here's the OrgUser.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class OrgUser extends Model {

    protected $table = 'org_user';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you expected to have actually exists in **Eloquent**. In order to **attach/detach** related models you need to call **attach/detach** methods on the relations and pass a single ID or array of IDs:

```
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
$user->roles()->attach([$roleId1, $roleId2]);
$role->users()->attach($userId);
$role->users()->attach([$userId1, $userId2]);
```

See some more info at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-re lated-models - the examples are pretty close to your case, as it's also about **user-role many-to-many** relationship.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your very useful answer. I hope to try this out and have a more detailed look in about 20 minutes.

Comment: Each User should have a different Role for each Org. Wouldn't `$user->roles()->attach($roleId)` set the same Role for all Orgs???

Comment: This won't set org_id at all. In order to set org_id you'd need to do $user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['org_id' => $orgId]); This will link user to role and set org_id to $orgId. If you want to enforce different roles per user for each organization you'll need to add unique constraints for (user_id, role_id, org_id) in the database. It would be useful to check for that before data is sent to the database doing the validation with laravel.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you. But in my case, I have Org-hasMany-User and User-belongsToMany-Org relations. I don't have a User-Role relation. In my case, Users have a per-Org authorisation level with "role_id" being an extra field in the OrgUser pivot table. Please bear with me - I am new to Eloquent and relational modeling.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't notice. Then you need to change the logic a bit. $user->orgs()->attach($orgId, ['role_id' => $roleId]); The second argument is the additional pivot data. Moreover, I think it should be possible to define both orgs() and roles() relations in your User model, the first declaring role_id as additional, the second declaring org_id. Just make sure both relations use the same table. Then you should be able to do both $user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['org_id'=>$orgId]) and $user->orgs()->attach($orgId, ['role_id' => $role_id]);

Comment: Wow. Do you do this professionally? It's very elegant code. With your advice, the following worked for me: `$user->orgs()->attach($orgID,['user_id'=>$userID,'role_id'=>$roleID]);`. I will implement the tip you gave me regarding having a User->roles() function. Currently, my Role table is just floating with no connections in my Schema builder. I will need to think about this to get my head around it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass user_id. It will be taken from the $user you're using.

Comment: Hey, I tried to omit the "user_id", but I got this error: local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eamorr`.`org_user`, CONSTRAINT `org_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))'

Comment: In that case I suggest you use "'user_id' => $user->id " instaed of "'user_id' => $userID'" to make sure that used user_id belongs to the user you're linking orgs to

Comment: I tried $user->id but got the same contraint violation. Oh well. I'm happy enough to be explicit. I will put in the unique constraint like you said and have a think about putting in a User<->Role relation. You have been tremendously helpful.